# Dill deletes object when using "load"

Tags: python, dill

I'm having an error that is driving me nuts.  I generate some numerical simulation data `sim_data.dill` and save it to a directory on my computer using

```
with open(os.path.join(original_directory, 'sim_data.dill'), 'w' as f:
    dill.dump(outputs, f)
```

This data is about 1 Gb and takes a while to generate.  Now, I copied that file from `original_directory` to `new_directory` when I try to load it from a different program using

```
simfile  = '/new_directory/sim_data.dill'
with open(simfile, 'r') as f:
    outputs = dill.load(f)
```

One of two things happens:

1. the program says the file is missing with `UnpicklingError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: .../`**original_directory**`/sim_data.dill`.  This means dill puts in the `original_directory` in the metadata of the file and refuses to open it when the file is moved; truly appalling behavior.
2. when I copy the file back to `new_directory`, trying to open it gives an `EOFError` and dill ***changes the file to zero bytes, essentially deleting it***.  This is even worse.

I can read the file just fine by using a standard `with open(simfile, 'r') as f; print f.readlines()`, but obviously this does not help when trying to recover the internal class structure of the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is normal behavior for `dill`; please see:

https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/296

Paraphrasing: the file location is part of the file handle to be pickled, and so unpickling it without that information is impossible.  This means, apparently, that if you save a `.dill` file in one location, move the file manually (for example to a more convenient directory), and then try to open it again, it won't work.

In terms of the deletion issue, the author of the post above recommends to  use `fmode=FMODE_PRESERVEDATA` or one of the other file modes listed at 
https://github.com/matsjoyce/dill/blob/087c00899ef55f31d36e7aee51a958b17daf8c91/dill/dill.py#L136-L145

Comment: This is a comment (a valuable one), which you can expand into an answer by summarizing the relevant portions of the linked content.

Comment: alright, i modified the comment above to reflect the full answer

Comment: Much better. Vote flipped

Comment: This is correct.  The default behavior of `dill` is to store a file by reference... so that's using the path to the file.  However, by changing `fmode`, you can store the file contents.  This is probably an under-documented feature of `dill` (I'd know, as I'm the original author).